# Get the score of a single sample in a multivariable model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to make a simple scikit-learn example work, but I keep getting the error: `multiclass-multioutput is not supported`.

The first part of my code, which follows any basic tutorial, works as predicted:

```
>>> from sklearn import ensemble
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> dataset = datasets.load_linnerud()
>>> X, y = dataset.data, dataset.target
>>> clf = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500)
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
>>> clf.predict([X[0]])
array([[ 191.,   36.,   50.]])
```

However, when I try to get a prediction score, I get the following error:

```
>>> clf.score([X[0]], [y[0]])
(...)
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

When working with `datasets.load_iris()`, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? How can I get the score of a single sample in a multivariable model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try swapping `RandomForestRegressor` in for `RandomForestClassifier`. The docs for  `load_linnerud()` show that it is a regression problem. Doing that made the code work for me.